# PDO MySQL UTF-8: Data read from database not showing correctly

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, pdo

`show variables`:

```
character_set_client        utf8
character_set_connection    utf8
character_set_database      utf8
character_set_filesystem    binary
character_set_results       utf8
character_set_server        latin1
character_set_system        utf8
collation_connection        utf8_general_ci
collation_database          utf8_unicode_ci
collation_server            latin1_swedish_ci
```

Data inserted is UTF-8 and shows correctly in the database, html header is set to utf-8, meta-tag is set to utf-8. All the content on the site (not coming from database) shows correctly), just not the content from the database.

Connection (PDO):

```
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$database;charset=utf8",$username,$password,array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));
```

So, I assume it has something to do with the output of `show variables` as it shows that the server's character set and collation are not utf-8? However, I run other sites on the same local server without any problems. Any idea where I could look to get it right?

Comment: `SET NAMES utf8` is deprecated, you pass it as charset parameter already, try without that one. (but do *not* add it again if it does not yet solve your issue).

Comment: @hakre: thx for your help, it works now. do you want to post an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your PDO connection:

```
new PDO(
    "mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$database;charset=utf8",
                                           ############
    $username, $password, array(
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"
                                         ##############
    )
);
```

You are making use of SQL `SET NAMES utf8` which is deprecated. You *should* not use it any longer. And actually you are already making use of the charset parameter in the PDO DSN string which is the recommended way: `charset=utf8`.

Just remove the `SET NAMES utf8` init command and you should be fine.

```
new PDO(
    "mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$database;charset=utf8",
    $username, $password
);
```